# Untar files from a huge tarball, but only created between two timestamps

Tags: linux, find, tar

I would like to untar only that files created between 2024-02-19 01:00:00 and 2024-02-19 02:00:00 from a huge tarball.

I don't know how should I combine the tar and the find commands, because I can't run the find in a tar.

Thank you for your help,
Andrew

Comment: What operating system are you using? What implementation of `tar` or `pax` do you have access to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an ad hoc script that should work, perhaps with some tweaks, on most Unix servers out there. It doesn't support some unusual names, such as newlines in file names or spaces in user names and group names, so check your data. It works by filtering the output of `tar -tv`.

```
tar -tvf a.tar | perl -l -ne 's/-([^ ]* +){3}(2024-02-19 01:[0-9][0-9])(:[0-9][0-9])? // or next; s/[\t \x22\x27\\]/\\$&/g; print' >file-list.txt
<file-list.txt xargs tar -xvf a.tar
```

The part that matches the desired time interval is `2024-02-19 01:[0-9][0-9]`. If you don't even have Perl, you can use sed or awk instead. If your `tar` doesn't like `tar -tvf FILENAME`, try `tar tvf FILENAME` or whatever variation your `tar` needs.

You may need to tweak the filter if your `tar` outputs a different format. The filter above works with GNU tar and BusyBox. With BSD tar, the user and group names are separated by a space and recent months are shown differently, so you need some tweaks:

```
tar -tvf a.tar | perl -l -ne 's/-([^ ]* +){5}(Feb 19 01:[0-9][0-9])(:[0-9][0-9])? // or next; s/[\t \x22\x27\\]/\\$&/g; print' >file-list.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

The `star` implementation of `tar` from [schilytools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/) has an embedded `find`, the same as in `sfind` or the `find` builtin of the `bosh` shell, both also in schilytools, though within `star`, the predicates can apply to properties of archive members instead of files on the filesystem when used in e`x`traction mode.

That `find` also supports the `-newerXY` predicates from BSDs.

So:

```
star xf file.tar -find -newermt 2024-02-19T00:59:59 ! -newermt 2024-02-19T02:00:00
```

Would extract the archive members whose recorded modification time is in that range.

With GNU tools (including GNU `tar`, sometimes called `gtar`, but generally `tar` on GNU systems), one approach could be to use its `--to-command` to pipe archive members to some command where the modification time of the member is made available in the `TAR_MTIME` environment variable:

```
START=$(date -d 2024-02-19T01:00:00 +%s) \
  END=$(date -d 2024-02-19T02:00:00 +%s) \
  tar -xf file.tar --to-command='
    if
      [ "$TAR_MTIME" -ge "$START" ] &&
        [ "$TAR_MTIME" -le "$END" ]
    then
      mkdir -p -- "$(dirname -- "$TAR_FILENAME")" &&
        cat > "$TAR_FILENAME" &&
        touch -d "@$TAR_MTIME" -- "$TAR_FILENAME"
    fi'
```

Beware it only extracts regular files (the first occurrence thereof if there are several hardlinks to the same file in the archive), doesn't preserve any metadata other than the mtime with `touch`.

Comment: Saves me completing my "parse the table of contents first" attempt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't install anything on that server. :(
Is it possible somehow to do this with the standard tar and find commands? Andrew

Comment: `tar` is no longer a standard command, it was removed from X/Open decades ago.

Comment: [`pax`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html#tag_20_92) is the standard command to extract `tar` archives (though there's no guarantee that formats other than pax and ustar be supported), and the `-o listopt` needed to format the timestamps in a useful format is not supported by all implementations.